# creating word documents from a winforms application

Tags: c#, winforms, ms-word

I have a C# winforms application with a sql server backend and want to be able to create word documents from within my application and populate them with basic information like addresses, references etc.  I've been browsing online for ideas but am struggling getting started on this subject.

Could someone please point me in the right direction.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As a starting point go to this link [Office Development With Visual Studio](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/hh133430.aspx)
then [download](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=20479) and install the requested libraries.

The subject is very broad and cannot be answered with precise details.
However just as you have requested, this is a direction:

- Create a DOT document and fill it with MergeFields where the data from
  SqlServer will be written to.
- Add the references to the Office Interop Word library in your project
- Declare the required Application and Document instance vars
- Read your data from the database and open the DOT file using the Office Word library
- Search in the DOT file the relative MergeField and update its text
- Save the DOT file as document in your folder.

As you can see, each of these steps worth questions by itself. So you have a lot of work to do

Comment: I'm using MS Word 2010 and the MrgeFields button is greyed out.  I've read up on this and it says I need to add a Datasource to activate the Merge buttons, but I want to sent the data programatically rather than link the Word document to an existing list or datasource.  How do I add MergeFields in Word without specifying a datasource / existing list?

Comment: No, you don't need a datasource. You could add a MergeField simply using the Insert Field menu. Now I don't have here Word2010, but I'm sure is still there somewhere.

Comment: Found it! Choose Quick Parts->Field from the Insert tab’s Text group. Select MergeField from the Field list, give it a name (something to remember your database field) and press OK (I'm omitting the formats and other options that you could find useful)

Answer (score 0):

What you need to look for are Report Designers , where you can edit them from code and  export  in many formats including word , pdf etc. 
you can look for Crystal Reports , Devexpress XtraReports and also there are many that are free .